# inconsistent results for basename?

Tags: zsh, macos, command-line

In the following, why is the **third** instance of `basename` including the file's enclosing directory?

```
WGroleau@MBP Music % basename Korean/kr_audio.tbz
kr_audio.tbz
WGroleau@MBP Music % basename ./Korean/kr_audio.tbz
kr_audio.tbz
WGroleau@MBP Music % time find . -type f -exec echo "$(basename "{}") ++ $(dirname "{}")" \; > /tmp/tmp
find . -type f -exec echo "$(basename "{}") ++ $(dirname "{}")" \; > /tmp/tmp  3.93s user 6.74s system 87% cpu 12.181 total
WGroleau@MBP Music % head !$
head /tmp/tmp
./Tx-01-00.mp3 ++ .
./Korean/kr_audio.tbz ++ .
./syn_HCA001-Cem.m4a ++ .
./Cetera.amad ++ .
./.DS_Store ++ .
./Japanese/JAI.tbz ++ .
./.localized ++ .
./iTunes SongKong/iTunes Library Extras.itdb ++ .
./iTunes SongKong/iTunes Music Library.xml ++ .
./iTunes SongKong/.DS_Store ++ .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took some digging but the answer is available in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175844/use-basename-in-find-exec):

- Process substitution (the `$(...)` part) occurs before `find` gets even executed
- So before `find` even starts, `$(basename "{}"` gets executed returning `{}`, turning your command into `find . -type f -exec echo "{}" \;`
- Now `find` starts and just echos each file found.

The output of `dirname` just *looked* right because `dirname {}` (or actually `dirname ANY-FILE`) always returns `.` (see the part after *Either the dir is "/" or there are no slashes* in [dirname.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1353.100.2/gen/FreeBSD/dirname.c.auto.html)).

As an alternative you can use

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$(basename $1) ++ $(dirname $1)"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up printing them to /tmp/tmp and then doing the echo line-by-line on that.  The second part (dirname) is also explained in the man pages.